# Trouble installing AspectJ on Eclipse 3.6.1

Tags: java, eclipse, eclipse-plugin, aspectj

When following these [instructions](http://techscienceinterest.blogspot.com/2010/02/how-to-install-aspectj-in-eclipse-35.html), I get the following error dialog

[image]

If you cannot read the message, it reads as follows

> An error occurred while collecting
>   items to be installed session context
>   was:(profile=SDKProfile,
>   phase=org.eclipse.equinox.internal.p2.engine.phases.Collect,
>   operand=, action=). Unable to read
>   repository at
>   http://download.eclipse.org/tools/ajdt/36/update/plugins/org.aspectj.ajde_1.6.11.20110304135300.jar.
>   Read timed out

Has anyone else encountered this? And if so, is there a workaround?

**EDIT**

Well it appears that someone else has -- [link](http://www.eclipse.org/forums/index.php/m/675752/).

Comment: are you behind a proxy ?

Comment: then you probably need to configure eclipse for that

Comment: http://help.eclipse.org/helios/index.jsp?topic=/org.eclipse.platform.doc.user/reference/ref-net-preferences.htm

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, as my edit indicates, the problem was due to connectivity issues.